# Составить оптимальный запрос в PHP MySQL

Tags: php, оптимизация, mysql

Всем привет.

Помогите, плз, оптимизировать код. Вот он сам:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `video_dating` ORDER BY id DESC",$db);
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $result_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `go-users` WHERE id='".$myrow['author']."'",$db);
    $myrow_u = mysql_fetch_array($result_user);
//параметры дальше выводятся
}
```

А я пытаюсь сделать сложный запрос, но что-то не выходит. 
Вот что пишу:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `video_dating.author`,`go-users.id`  FROM `video_dating` JOIN  `go-users` ON `video_dating.author`=`go-users.id` ",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

В итоге пишет:

> Ошибка базы данных. MySQL
> пишет:Unknown column
> 'video_dating.author' in 'field list'

Помогите, плз. 
Вообще как можно упростить код вышеподанный рабочий, самый верхний? Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять

```
SELECT `video_dating.author`,`go-users.id`
```

На

```
SELECT `video_dating`.`author`,`go-users`.`id`
```

и далее тоже. В кавычки берется каждый идентификатор. Т.е.

```
`идентификатор таблицы`.`идентификатор поля`
```

**Обновление**

Обращаться к полям можно

- по полному имени `таблица`.`поле`
- если для таблицы задан псевдоним, то по `псевдоним`.`поле`
- в выражении select, чтоб выбрать оба поля, например id из одной таблицы и из другой, можно задать всевдоним для выбираемого поля select `таблица`.`поле` as псевдоним.

Пример того, как обычно выглядят запросы с псевдонимами:

```
SELECT vd.author, vd.id as vd_id, gu.id as gu_id
FROM `video_dating` as vd 
  JOIN  `go-users` as gu ON vd.author=gu.id
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, ошибка пропала, буду знать)

Comment: а еще у меня id в двух таблицах, как обратится к одной?

Comment: @Dminko93, обращаться к полям можно 

* по полному имени `таблица`.`поле`
* если для таблицы задан псевдоним, то по `псевдоним`.`поле`
* в выражении select, чтоб выбрать оба поля, например id из одной таблицы и из другой, можно задать всевдоним для выбираемого поля select `таблица`.`поле` as псевдоним. 

Пример того, как обычно выглядят запросы с псевдонимами:

    SELECT vd.author, vd.id as vd_id, gu.id as gu_id
    FROM `video_dating` as vd 
      JOIN  `go-users` as gu ON vd.author=gu.id